# A Times-like font, but only the contour

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm looking for a serif font similar (ideally, identical) to this one from p. 206 of the PDF Reference, 6th edition, 2006:

[image: Contour only Times]

It looks like a Times contour, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What PDF reference is that?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: [This one](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf). If it helps, I'm only really interested in the letter 'n', and only in the rather large size seen in the illustration above.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use a Times font, add a stroke and fill white?

Comment: @BillyKerr: Maybe, if I had a clue how to do it. I should add that this glyph will then be subjected to programmatic transformations, and should behave like a normal vector font would under these circumstances.

Comment: What software do you have?  It could be done easily in Adobe Illustrator or the free software Inkscape(dot)org  - both are vector image editors.

Comment: @BillyKerr: The thing is, I'm not a graphic designer. I have zero skills in such matters. All I want to do is use TeX to try and replicate the illustration shown above and its sundry variations shown on the same page of the PDF specifications. It would be immensely easier for me to just get a hold of a suitable font.

Comment: I understand, however in case you are interested, here's a screenshot of Inkscape. http://imgur.com/a/sk7iO - I simply added a white fill and stroke to the text.  Inkscape can even render SVGs, which I am sure you could probably use in your TeX document.

Comment: @BillyKerr: Would you be so kind as to do it for me? I only need the letter 'n' and only at the size of 50pt (which will then be stretched, rotated and shifted, and should behave like a vector graphic would under these actions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63014/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-evan-aad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stone Serif Semi Bold Regular seems to be a perfect fit.

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/stone-serif/pro-semibold/

[image]

The stroke on the letter is .3 if you are trying to replicate that as well.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, no. This glyph is clearly bolder than the screenshot the Asker posted. Moreover, the shape of the top of the stem is flat in your answer, while it's curved in the question.

Comment: Thanks. This is very close, but I don't think this is it for two reasons. (1) In Times New Roman the top of the upright part is straight and horizontal, whereas in the glyph I posted it is slanting and a little curved, (2) In Times New Roman the "legs" are slightly thicker than the space between them, whereas in the glyph I posted it is the other way round. Nice try, though.

Comment: 100% Correct, I updated my answer with a better fit!

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect! You don't happen to know if there's an outline version of this font, do you?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't look like there is. Your only option is to manually expand the font to then stroke it.